# Mounting .iso image in Linux Mint with incorrect filename encoding

Tags: ubuntu, mount, iso-image, character-encoding

I am trying to mount some ISO files but have filename encoding issue. The .iso file in question is here: https://archive.org/download/cpcfan-200510b/200510B.iso

Mount command and incorrect filename:

```
$ sudo mount 200510B.iso /tmp/cd
mount: /tmp/cd: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
$ ls /tmp/cd/
''$'\311\361\326\333''6'$'\272\305'   entertainment   mfc42.dll   software                                  web
 autorun.inf                          flash           movie       study
 back.mp3                             games           music       topic
 dm                                   hard            pcfan.exe  ''$'\271\342\305''̵'$'\274\266\301''.txt'
 dos                                  material        pcfan.ico   wallpaper
```

However, in Python I was able to decode the filename of the .txt file as an example correctly:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from glob import glob
>>> files = glob(u'/tmp/cd/*.txt')
>>> files[0].encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('GB2312')
'/tmp/cd/光盘导读.txt'
```

So it appears that the filenames are incorrectly coded GB2312 as utf8, but when mounted in Windows the filenames are correct. I have tried different `iocharset` values with no success.

My question is, what would be the correct mount command with proper settings to mount this iso?